# How to display configurable product swatches when product is Out of stock

Tags: configurable-product, products, magento2.1.6

I have a configurable products with few sizes, let's say : `123, 160, M, S, L, XL`

When I put products **M** and **S** on qty **0**, which means it is `out of stock`, then sizes disappear form the swatches option.

I was expected to see also out of stock products with a special class and to be non clickable, but  out of stock products disappear.

I found a solution and I will post my answer. Maybe that will help someone.

Comment: Can you please add the full code? The link for module doesn't work anymore.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/151595)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/151595)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/151595)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve this issue:

**Step 1**

I installed this module( for some other versions of magento maybe this will work without step 2)

https://github.com/mjankiewicz/MagentoConfigurableProduct

**Step 2**

Create a module with:

**etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable" type="Vendor\Namespace\Block\Outstock" />
</config>
```

then create **Block/Outstock.php**

```
<?php 

namespace vendor\namespace\Block;

class Outstock extends \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable
{

   public function getAllowProducts()
    {
        if (!$this->hasAllowProducts()){
             $skipSaleableCheck = 1;
             $products = $skipSaleableCheck ?
             $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($this->getProduct(), null) :
                $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getSalableUsedProducts($this->getProduct(), null);
            $this->setAllowProducts($products);
        }
        return $this->getData('allow_products');
    }
}
```

After this run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Of course that you can combine those 2 modules. You can take `/Helper/Data.php` form the first module **JanSoft_ConfigurableProduct** and put this into the second module, or the oposite.

Comment: Thanks it working, but how can i disable the option that is out of stock?

Comment: i am not sure that i undestand your question

Comment: i put your code and it is showing now all options of configurable products including the associative products that are out of stock,  i want to show them but not selectable

Comment: please help how can i make the out of stock options " non clickable"

Comment: there are not clickable if you follow those 2 steps

Comment: No its not working, may be magento version issue :(  
thanks

Comment: be sure that your block form step 2 is override

Comment: Its only works on icons not on dropdown :(

Comment: Will this work for 2.1.9?

Comment: @AlinLupoiu should I be replacing vendor/namspace (Block/Outstock.php) and Vendor/Namespace (di.xml) with my own "vendor" and "namespace"?

Comment: @Jason, yes so you will your vendor and namespace

Comment: @AlinLupoiu sorry for such a late reply.  If I'm going to combine the modules, how do I combine the etc/di.xml files ?  Currently file structure is: 

app/code/JanSoft/CongurableProduct/
...etc/di.xml (containing original jansoft code)
...Helper/data.php (containing original jansoft code)
...Block/outstock.php (containing your code)

with this option, should I change Vendor\Namespacer to JanSoft\ConfigurableProduct in your code that you posted for di.xml and Block/Outstock.php?

Comment: Alan, I have verified that this solution does not work in a stock installation of Magento 2.2.5.  Can you tell us what version you are using to make this work?

Comment: is this still working 
this url https://github.com/mjankiewicz/MagentoConfigurableProduct doesn't work anyone help

Comment: but how can i disable the option that is out of stock

Answer (score 1):

You can also override the plugin to display the swatches as well as dropdown option if product is out of stock.

1)etc/di/xml.

```
<type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Plugin\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\InStockOptionSelectBuilder">
        <plugin name="Magento_ConfigurableProduct_Plugin_Model_ResourceModel_InStockOptionSelectBuilder"
                type="Vendor\Mymodule\Plugin\Attribute\InStockOptionSelector"/>
    </type>
```

2)Plugin\Attribute

```
namespace Vendor\Mymodule\Plugin\Attribute;

use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Status;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\OptionSelectBuilderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Select;

class InStockOptionSelector extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Plugin\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\InStockOptionSelectBuilder
{
    private $stockStatusResource;

    public function __construct(Status $stockStatusResource)
    {
        parent::__construct($stockStatusResource);
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionSelectBuilderInterface $subject
     * @param Select $select
     * @return Select
     */
    public function afterGetSelect(OptionSelectBuilderInterface $subject, Select $select)
    {

        return $select;
    }
}
```

3) override block in di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" type="Vendor\Mymodule\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable"/>
```

4)Configurable.php

```
namespace Vendor\Mymodule\Block\Product\View\Type;

use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ConfigurableAttributeData;
use Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\Format;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;

class Configurable extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayUtils $arrayUtils, \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder, \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Data $helper, \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $catalogProduct, CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer, PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency, ConfigurableAttributeData $configurableAttributeData, array $data = [], $localeFormat = null, $customerSession = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $arrayUtils, $jsonEncoder, $helper, $catalogProduct, $currentCustomer, $priceCurrency, $configurableAttributeData, $data, $localeFormat, $customerSession);
    }

    public function getAllowProducts()
    {
        if (!$this->hasAllowProducts()) {
            $products = [];
            $skipSaleableCheck = $this->catalogProduct->getSkipSaleableCheck();
            $allProducts = $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($this->getProduct(), null);
            foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
                if ($product->isSaleable() || $skipSaleableCheck == 1) {
                    $products[] = $product;
                }
            }
            $this->setAllowProducts($products);
        }
        return $this->getData('allow_products');
    }

}
```

Hope so it will help .

Answer (score 0):

**Add into di.xml**

```
 <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable">
        <plugin name="Vendor_Module::disable-stock-filter" type="Vendor\Module\Plugins\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable"/>
 </type>
```

**create file Configurable.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugins\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type;

use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable as NativeConfigurable;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable\Product\Collection;

class Configurable
{ 
    public function afterGetUsedProductCollection(NativeConfigurable $subject, $collection)
    {
        $collection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true);

        return $collection;
    }
}
```